# How to redirect mobile users and pc users to another url but are in the same web page

Tags: php, redirect

How do I direct phone users to `m.test.com    //for mobile*`

and PC users to `test.com   // pc user` 
in php? Or should I do it in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is a browser switch: You act on the information, which browser is requesting and from which OS. You can do this either on the server (PHP) or on the client (JS):

- Server sided: Use either `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` or `get_browser()`, then send a redirect via `header()` as needed
- Client sided: User `navigator.userAgent` and friends to decide, then set `location.href` to do the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial [How To Redirect Mobile Users On Your Website](http://blog.woorank.com/2014/06/how-to-redirect-mobile-users-on-your-website/)

> The PHP Method
>
> If your site is coded in PHP you can use this method to redirect your
>   mobile users. The advantage of using this method is that you are not
>   limited to browsers that run on JavaScript. However, you will have to
>   list multiple user-agents.
>
> For this script to work your page extensions must be .php and your
>   hosting account must support PHP. Add the following code to your
>   website’s <head> section.

```
<?php
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],”iPhone”);
    $android = strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],”Android”);
    $palmpre = strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],”webOS”);
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],”BlackBerry”);
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],”iPod”);
    if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
    {
        echo “<script>window.location=’http://m.site.com'</script>”;
    }
?>
```

You will find this code in this post titled [Simple PHP Mobile Website
Redirect Code](http://wallydavid.com/simple-php-mobile-website-redirect-code).